# Android: animating view in onClick()

Tags: java, android, animation, onclick, android-imageview

I have ImageView that I want to animate it whenever user clicks on it.

So I ended up with this simple solution:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView.animate()
                    .rotationX(360).rotationY(360)
                    .setDuration(1000)
                    .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        }
```

It works just perfect, **but only FIRST TIME** (first click plays animation, after that animation does not work at all).

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset the rotation before or after each animation. For example:

```
imageView.animate()
    .rotationX(360).rotationY(360)
    .setDuration(1000)
    .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            imageView.setRotationX(0);
            imageView.setRotationY(0);
        }
    });
```